# why return false is not working in below code

Tags: javascript

there are some anchor tags in my code, But I dont want ,by clicking on link page should load link, I want to alert when click on anchor tag , and further, click event  should not get executes.

```
window.onload=function(){ 
  var x=document.getElemenByTagName('a');
  for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    x[i].addEventListener('click',doAlert,false);
  function doAlert(){
    alert('not allowed')
    return false;
  }
}
```

***my problem here is anchor tag gets executed***

Comment: Indentation is a thing that you should use.

Comment: misspelled : getElementsByTagName NOT getElemenByTagName

Answer (score 2):

you have misspelled getElemenByTagName...

it is:

**getElementsByTagName** NOT getElemenByTagName

Comment: To prove this is the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/UNLaS/ (only change I made to OP's code is that call)

Answer (score 0):

`function doAlert(event){
  event.preventDefault(); 
  alert('not alowed');
}`

Comment: True, but you're not accounting for `window.event` instead of the `event` object being passed to the handler. Anyways, `return false;` is equivalent in this context, except that it must execute last in the function to prevent default behavior.